# Encoding issue for [] in req URL in contentful-management node module

Tags: node.js, contentful, contentful-management

We are using this node module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/contentful-management
for contentful API access. In the documentation it says entries can filtered by
space.getEntries({ 'sys.id[in]': [1,2]}) but the URL it generates is below.

https://api.contentful.com:443/spaces//entries?content_type=site5&fields.country%5Bin%5D=%5B'US', 'India'%5D&fields.pinCode%5Bmatch%5D=10007&access_token=

it converts '[' and ']' to encoded value causing a failure in the URL response. This is done automatically by the module. Is there way around for this.

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a mistake in the documentation (which I just fixed).

Try doing `space.getEntries({ 'sys.id[in]': '1,2'})` instead.